# Surprisingly high number of ratings on few days of MovieLens dataset

Tags: recommendation-engine, movie, mahout-recommender

The MovieLens 20M dataset has unusually high number of ratings on few days such as :

```
2000-11-20    91753
2005-03-22    76568
1999-12-11    65077
2008-10-29    55163
```

[image: number of ratings over time]

What could be the reason for such a weird observation ?

Comment: What are you looking for here?  Guesses?  My guess is that there were bots that were screwing up the system, or bugs that caused an inordinate amount of entries.  Seems to me the question is best posed to Movielens themselves.

Comment: MovieLens maintainer here. @gview offers good suggestions. Also, we periodically get bursts of real activity from running experiments or getting publicity in the media. I don't know the specifics for those particular dates.